# SQL Query merge

Tags: sql, hana

I am working on a scenario where for example I need to search customers by telephone and/or email address.
for example

```
if :lv_telephone <> '' then
lt_phone = select a.customer from customer_master a inner join telephone as b on a.address = b.address;
end if;

if :lv_email <> '' then 
lt_email = select a.customer from customer_master a inner join email as b on a.address = b.address;
end if;
```

DB - HANA.

I want to create one final result merging both email and phone table only if they both have result set. Any pointers on how to do it?

Comment: Please share more details, like the table structure, sample input data, the expected output corresponding to that input data, and which database system you are using

Comment: Done. Added information.

Comment: Where's the sample input and output data?

Answer (score 2):

You may avoid any script logic and "merge" your results in a plain SQL with conditions on variables (regardless of their source):

```
select a.customer
from customer_master a
  left join telephone t
    on a.address = t.address
      and lv_telephone != ''
  left join email e
    on a.address = e.address
      and lv_email != ''
where 1 = 1
  /*Applies only when lv_telephone is not ''*/
  and map(lv_telephone, '', '', t.address) is not null
  /*Applies only when lv_email is not ''*/
  and map(lv_email, '', '', e.address) is not null
```

This may also be adapted if you need to filter by passed values: compare with variable value instead of null. If variables come from SQLScript code, this can be embedded into SQLScript code. If they come from outside (e.g. some external language communicating with your DB), you may use bind variables and plain SQL withour additional script wrapper.

Below is example with standard SAP tables:

```
create procedure test_sp ( in iv_tel nvarchar(10), in iv_email nvarchar(10))
as
begin

  select b.*
  from sapdbh.t006 as b
    left join sapdbh.t006a as t
      on b.msehi = t.msehi
        and t.spras = 'R'
        and :iv_tel != ''
    left join sapdbh.t006t as e
      on b.dimid = e.dimid
        and e.spras =  'R'
        and :iv_email != ''
  where 1 = 1
    and case
          when :iv_tel != ''
          then t.msehi
          else ''
        end is not null
    and case
          when :iv_email != ''
          then e.dimid
          else ''
        end is not null
        
;
end;
```

And execution plans below (I didn't use `mandt` in join so you may observe results are multiplied when join is introduced):

- With `call test_sp('', '');` one table accessed.
  [image]
- With `call test_sp('X', '');` two tables accessed.
  [image]
- With `call test_sp('X', 'X');` three tables accessed.
  [image]